# Настройка Swagger в приложении на Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Хочу настроить swagger для документирования REST-сервиса на `spring boot`. Следую гайду на [этом сайте](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Сначала я добавил зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Потом добавил файл конфигурации спринга:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

Написано, что этой конфигурации достаточно для интеграции сваггера в существующий проект. Автор пишет, что проверить работоспособность сваггера можно по ссылке `http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest/api/v2/api-docs`, по которой возвращается json. Но на порту 8080 у меня висит `RethinkDB`, а мое приложение работает на порту 8086. Один из моих эндпоинтов имеет вид `http://localhost:8086/api/invoice`.

Я пробовал разные комбинации адресов, например, `http://localhost::8086/api/api-docs`, но от сваггера нет никакого отклика. Как его настроить?

Comment: в логах пишет как именно замапил сваггер. проверьте логи во время запуска. `http://localhost::8086/api/swagger-ui.html` попробуйте

Answer (score 2):

Для версии 2.9.2 у меня заработала проверка на http://localhost:8888/v2/api-docs (только порт поменяйте на ваш - 8086).
Сам UI находится по адресу http://localhost:8888/swagger-ui.html (вам опять порт поменять на 8086).

Если у вас используется своя реализация интерфейса ResponseBodyAdvice, то в аннотации к нему нужно указать пакет, на который этот совет действует, иначе Swagger не будет работать.

@ControllerAdvice("your.package")
public class ResponseBodyAdviceImpl implements ResponseBodyAdvice {
...
}